# R dplyr mutate_at accessing colnames

Tags: r, dplyr

How could one access the column name being processed by `dplyr::mutate_at`?

Let's say we would like to convert a column of a data frame into factors with levels stored in a separate list.

```
df <- data.frame("C1"=c("A","B","C"), "C2"=c("D","E","F"))
df
  C1 C2
1  A  D
2  B  E
3  C  F

lst <- list("C2"=c("F","E","D"), "C3"=c("G","H","I"))
lst
$C2
[1] "F" "E" "D"

$C3
[1] "G" "H" "I"
```

All of the following trigger error or replace all the column values by NA:

```
df %>%
mutate_at(vars(C2), function(x) factor(x, levels=lst$.))

df %>%
mutate_at(vars(C2), function(x) factor(x, levels=lst[[colnames(.)]]))

df %>%
mutate_at(vars(C2), function(x){col = as.name(.); factor(x, levels=lst$col))
```

Comment: `mutate_at` has been suprceded by `across` fucntionality in `dplyr` v1.0.0.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Not an option for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` in base R or `map2` from `purrr` after getting the common columns using `intersect`.

```
cols <- intersect(names(lst), names(df))
df[cols] <- Map(function(x, y) factor(x, levels = y), df[cols], lst[cols])
```

Or

```
df[cols] <- purrr::map2(df[cols], lst[cols], ~factor(.x, levels = .y))
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. However I would need for now to stick to `dplyr` (or at least using pipes)

Comment: There is no need of pipes here but if you insist would `df[cols] <- df[cols] %>% map2(lst[cols], ~factor(.x, levels = .y))` work?

Comment: What I meant was piping from the entire `df` and not subsetting by columns with `df[cols]`.

Comment: @u31889 Sorry, I am not aware about a `dplyr` way to do this (and I doubt it exists). After reading your question this method seemed more natural to me hence I posted it as an answer. Using `dplyr` there might be a very convoluted way to do this please post it as an answer if you find it.